# Crystal report hierarchical group indentation for only one field

Tags: crystal-reports

How do we set the indentation for only one field for hierarchical group in crystal report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the Report menu select Hierarchical Grouping Options, set Group Indent to 0.
2. Right click the Group Header field and select Size and Position
3. Click the Conditional Formula button beside the X position value field.
4. This is the formula you will use

   HierarchyLevel (GroupingLevel({[Hierarchy Name] Node ID}))*200

Here you can see more details about [Hierarchies in Crystal Reports](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/BW+Hierarchies+in+Crystal+Reports)